# Android Studio; not sure which version to use

Tags: android-studio

For my android studio I have a hard time finding out which version of android studio I should use, for example: i'm not sure if I should use `kitkat`, `lollypop`, because I usually pick ice cream sandwich and after I pick that, when I get into opening my emulator, it opens once, then it gives the error; 
"

```
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks
emulator: device fd:780
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit."
```

And is that the result of picking the wrong version? please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear "The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit". What is your hardware specifications: CPU, RAM, ... ? It seems to be related to your hardware performance. Try with another PC.

In your question, there is also a confusion between Android Studio version (IDE) and Android version. Choosing the right Android version depends on what your application is supposed to do. For example if you want to deal with NFC tags you will not choose an android version < 4.0.0 because NFC is not supported on earlier versions.

When you create a new project in Android Studio there is always a **help me choose link** click on it
[image]

Comment: k thank you. My problem was solved, instead of using the emulator i just used an actual device, and it worked ty